# What modifier or plugin does uneven mesh division?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I know that this is a very strange question, but few mounts back I somehow made a box with uneven mesh and I don't remember how I did it. Probably used a modifier or plugin following a tutorial. Does anyone recognize or know what does that mesh division?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with a Subdivision Surface modifier set to "Simple" followed with a Decimate modifier set to "collapse" with a low ratio (I used 0.1).
[image: Result]

Comment: Great! for some reason not working in 2.91 but in 2.8 works great!